# Does Node.js itself have support for WebSocket?

Tags: node.js

I don't want to use any plugins or framework for Node.js. Does Node.js itself have support for WebSocket?

Comment: I'm not an expert in node but I think that `WebSocket` as you said is already integrated, see https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node alone doesn't suport WebSocket, you need another library like this :

https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node

Answer (score 0):

There are various [packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=websocket) available for integrating web sockets with node.js or you can use [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) framework.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense for anyone to not use any node modules. Node is a large eco-system and its functionalities are spread across different modules, so that developers can pick and choose things they need. Websocket libraries are non-essential, so they don't come pre-bundled.

**ws** is one of the more popular libraries. There are other similar libraries available, that can be found by searching the npm docs.

If you don't want to use any node module for some reason, you're going to have to rewrite the websocket logic from scratch. Node does have the "net" module pre-bundled, which contains the necessary TCP tools. I wouldn't recommend it.